# How to run Firestore in IE11?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, phaser-framework

i have developed a browsergame with Phaser 3 and store the data for highscore in Google Firebase.
I got no problem by using the browsers Chrome, Edge, Firefox or Safari. But by loading the website in IE11 i got a lot of errors shown in console.

[image]

I can't find any syntaxerror in main.js:

```
var graphics;
var touch = false;
var game; 

window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    //game configuration
    game = new Phaser.Game({
    "title": "infoteam-Universe",
    "width": 1920,
    "height": 1080,
    "type": Phaser.WEBGL,
    "audio": {disableWebAudio: true},
    "backgroundColor": "#88F",
    "parent": "game-container",
    "physics": {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: 1080 },
            debug: false,
        }
    },
    scene: [Boot],
    "scale": {
        "mode": Phaser.Scale.FIT,
        "autoCenter": Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH
    },
    "input": {
        activePointers: 3
    },
    dom: { 
        createContainer: true } 
    });

});

class Boot extends Phaser.Scene {
    
    constructor() {
        super ("Boot");
    }
    
    preload() {
        this.load.audio("background-soundtrack", "assets/audio/background-soundtrack.mp3");
        this.load.pack("preload-pack", "assets/preload-pack.json");
    }
    
    update() {
        //start first scene of game
        this.scene.start("Preload");
        
        /*if(!this.game.device.browser.safari || !this.game.device.browser.mobileSafari) {
            this.game.config.audio.disableWebAudio = false;
            console.log(this.game.config.audio.disableWebAudio);
        }*/
    }
    
}
```

And index.html:

```
<!--<script> var firebaseApp; </script>-->

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>infoteam-Universum</title>

    <script src="lib/phaser.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>


    <style>
        body {
            background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            color: azure;
        }

        #overlay {
            width: 5%;
            height: 5%;
            position: fixed;
            top: 90%;
            left: 93%;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            background-color: transparent;
            border: none;
            background-image: url(assets/images/startFullscreen.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
            text-align: center;
            display: inline-block;
            transition-duration: 0.4s;
            vertical-align: middle;      
            z-index: 2;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    
    <div id="game-container"></div>
    <input type="button" value="" onclick="openFullscreen()" id="overlay">

    <script>
        /* Get the element you want displayed in fullscreen mode (a video in this example): */
        var elem = document.getElementById("game-container");
        
        function openFullscreen() {
          if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
            elem.requestFullscreen();
          } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
            elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
          } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
            elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
          } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
            elem.msRequestFullscreen();
          }
        }
    </script>
    
      <!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    
      <!-- If you enabled Analytics in your project, add the Firebase SDK for Analytics -->
      <!--<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script-->
    
      <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

     <script>
        var firebaseApp;
        
        var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "",
            authDomain: "",
            databaseURL: "",
            projectId: "",
            storageBucket: "",
            messagingSenderId: "",
            appId: "",
            measurementId: ""
        };
    
        // Initialize Firebase
        firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        //firebase.analytics();

      </script>


    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Import the firebase cdn first and then the main.js

Comment: Unfortunately now i'm getting the same errors just in another order.

Comment: import all the firebase libraries (`firebase-app.js`, `firebase-analytics.js` and `firebase-firestore.js`) before the `main.js`

Comment: Can you confirm the order firebase cdns first then phaser.js then main.js @Felicia Debye